# How is this 4 bytes?

Tags: python, byte, bit

I am trying to understand how to manually read bytes from a file. In this case, the file is a bitmap image. This `b'\x7fcq\x7f'` and this `b'ds~d'` represent 4 bytes of data from my image file. Can someone explain to me how this can be or just how to manually read bytes?

Comment: The two symbols after `\x` are hexadecimal digits. So each byte can go from `\x00` (=0) to `\xFF` (=255). This is shown when the byte doesn't represent an ASCII character.

Comment: This means that the first byte string contains 4 bytes, representing `[7f, 'c', 'q', 7f]`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just 4 bytes. What you see is python's `bytes` representation of that data where ascii characters are used for the byte. Except when there isn't a viewable ascii for that byte, then you get a hex representation like `\x7f`. But this is just python showing the 4 bytes for humans.

Another way to view it is as a list of integers, one per byte

```
>>> data = b'\x7fcq\x7f'
>>> list(data)
[127, 99, 113, 127]
```